# How to not use by part to evaluate the following integration problem?

Tags: calculus

> Evaluate$$\int^1_02x^2\sqrt{x^2+4}dx$$without integration by parts.

This is a problem from my calculus homework. I've tried to sub. $x=2\tan u$, and it became $$32\int^{\arctan\frac{1}{2}}_0\tan^2 u\sec^3 u$$ Which needs by parts.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint

$$\tan^2u\sec^3u=\dfrac{\sin^2u}{\cos^5u}=\dfrac{\sin^2u}{\cos^6u}\cdot\cos u$$

As the exponent of cosine is odd, set $\sin u=y$

Then http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialFractionDecomposition.html

Answer (score 2):

$$\dfrac{d(\tan^mx\sec^nx)}{dx}=n\tan^{m+1}x\sec^{n+1}x+m\tan^{m-1}x\sec^{n+2}x$$

Integrate both sides with respect to $x$

Set $n+1=3,m+1=2$

Now $$\int\sec^{2r}x\ dx=\int(1+\tan^2x)^{n-1}\sec^2x\ dx=?$$